# Qt best way to invoke methods of QMainWindow from other widget

Tags: c++, qt

I have main window from type `QMainWindow`, then I set some widget and give this widget the `QMainWindow` as parent in its constructor , the `QMainWindow` passed as Object.
now I need from this widget invoke method from the QMainWindow. 
what will be the best way to do it ?

this is how the widget looks like:

```
DataListModel::DataListModel( QObject *parent ) :
             QStandardItemModel( 0, 0, parent ) 

{
// here I like to invoke some QMainWindow method? 
//can I cast somehow the parent ? or use some pointer ?

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the MainWindow is the parent of your DataListModel than you can cast it:

```
MainWindow *w = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent);
if(w == 0) {
 //error handling here
}
```

**edit**

For example this:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QStatusBar>
ScrollBar::ScrollBar(QWidget *parent) :
    QScrollBar(parent)
{
    MainWindow *w = qobject_cast<MainWindow*>(parent);

   if(w != 0) {
       qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO;
       QStatusBar *bar = w->statusBar();
       bar->hide();
   }
}
```

works fine

Comment: now as i check it again , this dosnt work , the cast doesn't give me the object pointer , its some hallow pointer ,

Comment: Tested with QObject base test class, works too. Check that you pass MainWindow instance to DataListModel ctor